# How should I upload a base64 image string retrieved from pouchdb to another api as a file?

Tags: angularjs, image, base64, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I have a base64 image format stored in pouchdb, now I want the same file to upload in particular API in server.

How do I get file path or file out of base64image as the API accepts only file so?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [blob-util](https://github.com/nolanlawson/blob-util). You can use PouchDB's attachment API to get Blobs out of the database (`getAttachment()`), and then use blob-util to convert those Blobs to a variety of different formats.